# CLLocation Manager using default location and not updating with actual location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

So I have no idea what happened. The code I had was working perfectly fine and then i worked around in story board for a bit and suddenly I started getting the error that my CLLocation was always nil when being unwrapped. I did everything i could think of or read online.

- added to .plist
- copied code in different spots
- moved the didUpdateLocations into viewDidLoad

If I update the scheme to have a default location then It just uses the default location the whole time and never updates with my current location, same when i try it on an actual device but if I leave it to none then the delegate method for error `didFailWithError` is called saying that the value returned was nil. I am losing it over here. Please Help.

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

      }  


 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("In the location, seems we got some shit --> didFailWithError: \(error.description)")

        }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location!.coordinate
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: self.geofireRef.child("Posts"))

        let center = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)

        let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 10)

        circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
        })

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
```

Comment: You are monitoring for significant location changes. These only occur after quite a while. You are aware of that? In the simulator it can take up to 5 minutes before seeing any updates. Those can be really inaccurate and you won't see updates immediately. Try it without significant location changes. I would also handle everything on the didUpdateLocations first before stopping it.

Comment: I did not know that but those were just additional attempts to try anything. After changing per your suggestion I still have the same problem.

Comment: I have updated my code but still having the same problem

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots. Have you checked your app settings to confirm that you haven't denied location permission?  Can maps find your  location on a device? When you simulate location on a device, sometimes locations services gets upset and you need to restart the device for it to work again. On the simulator you always need to simulate a location

Comment: Sorry. I'll update the post. How do i get to App settings to check if I the location got denied?

Comment: I made an additional project for the sole purpose of checking the users location and I have the exact same problem... what could that be?

Comment: You only get one update, you aware of that? Since when you get one location you stop location updates. If you remove the `self.locationManager.stopUpdateLocation()` you will get updates all the time. You can check your app settings in the general settings app of iOS. Not sure what your goal is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Even with that removed the delegate method `didUpdateLocations` is never called unless i give a default location to the scheme, however when i give it a default the only location I get returned is the default location that was set (London, Tokyo, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following bit of code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView = MKMapView()
    var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("In the location, seems we got some error \(error.description)")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location!.coordinate
        let center = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locValue, 2000, 2000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapView.centerCoordinate = locValue
        print(center)
    }
}
```

Setting the requirements in the `Info.plist` of course and enabling the location simulator in debug menu section:

[image: location simulator]

Gives me the following output:

```
<+37.33756603,-122.04120235> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/7/16, 11:27:25 PM Central European Summer Time
<+37.33756603,-122.04120235> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/7/16, 11:27:26 PM Central European Summer Time
```

Comment: So whenever the simulator is turned on the location set is set to none how do I get it to be set all the time? But even then i looked at my location online and the coordinates don't match with what CLLocation is reporting. Any Thoughts?

Comment: So for some reason when I run the project and go to Debug --> Simulate Locations the "Don't Simulate Location" is checked but when I open it when the app is not running everything is grey and the "Don't Simulate Location" is unchecked. How do i stop this!!!  I feel like we're so close!!!

Comment: Yea the simulator is not simulating your current location. It's simulating a basic standard predefined route around the Apple Campus. If you want your own location you need to use your device. And you can only simulate location inside your app. Not when your app is closed in xCode. Hope this gives you some answers. As long as you receive updates in your console you are fine. If you would like to see the effect of the simulator you should plot your location on the map and simulate it.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that makes sense I suppose. So there is no way to set the simulator's Debug -> Location -> City Bicycle ride to be permanent because right now I have to hurry up and change it before the view loads to get any workable results

Comment: Well the debug -> simulate location is always accessible. So you can set it anytime and your selection will be permanent. It will run all the time. Everytime I start up my application it will start with a city bicycle ride. I also just updated my code above with a Mapview so you have visual feedback of how the simulators location works. If you want location updates in the background (when your app is not on the foreground), then we are having a different conversation. It's possible but you need to setup some more things to get that working!

Comment: Oh. Everytime I run on the simulator the value for location under debug gets set right back to none for some reason. But besides that it looks like I have enough to go forward. Thanks @Wouter125

Comment: Don't close the simulator completely. Just keep it open until you are done working. You can just hit the stop and play button and it will start up your app without having to reopen the iOS simulator completely! Then still if I force quit my simulator the bicycle ride is still checked so not sure what's happening there. If you still have questions let me know!